# To get out of overlapping images in tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've added buttons to tableviewcell and now I added background images to those buttons which are taken in an array. I've added them by `[arrName objectatindex:indexPath.row]`. i got a problem that my tableview cells are added dynamically while swapping the cells from one to another. I got a problem that the button images are overlapping on one another after adding a cell which has already an image. please help me to get out of this.

Comment: code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `Clip Subviews` would help. In the XIB where you have defined your `UITableViewCell` choose that `UIButton` and in the interface builder select "clip subviews" -

[image]